# Multi-threaded access to SQLite using C# and EntityFramework

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm having trouble accessing sqllite db from multiple threads.

SqlLite outputs “SQLite error (5): Database is locked” frequently

A solution to this issue is explained [here](http://www.mintycode.com/post/58816954126/multi-threaded-access-to-sqlite-using-c-and-nhibernate) in case you are using NHibernate but i don't know how to apply that solution on EntityFramework.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

in particular how do I "manage the session scopes in order to reuse the same connection across multiple threads" ?

Comment: Do you share context between threads?

Comment: i tried to, but sqllite do not behave well in that case. Documentation say every thread should use its own instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using SQLCE 4.0 which turned out to manage multithreading and concurrent access perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you are exclusively using EF, just put all your data access around some kind of "DB Lock"

```
// Prevent concurrent access to database, MyDatabase.Lock is a public static object that I use for locking all data access
lock (MyDatabase.Lock)
{
    using (var context = new DbEntities())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: i have 100s threads, i think this is gonna slow down isn't it? anyway i'm gonna give it a try